# Use Octave/Matlab combine multiple blobs in close proximity into one blob

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, binary, octave

I am currently working on a project that is utilizing traffic camera video streams and analyzing them. I have written an algorithm in Octave, a .m file, that is able to return the outlines of multiple cars as individual blobs, and its outline and center coordinates. Specifically, for the blob part, I am using BWLabel and BWBoundaries and applying it to a binary image that I have created where 1 is car and 0 is background, according to the rest of my algorithm. I have an image below that shows this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpeJ6.jpg

All of the blobs are cars, including the one with about 5 blobs next to each other. All of these blobs are one van, but the different colors and features have thrown off the detection system. Does anyone know of a way to easily combine all of these blobs that are in close proximity into one blob. I am talking about an existing algorithm or function that is already in Octave packages or Matlab toolboxes. If not, I will write the code from scratch and make it happen. This question was just a call to ask if there are pre-existing solutions, not a call to write code for me, unless you want to :).

Thanks for your help,

AeroVTP

Comment: Did you try morphological closing (imclose in matlab)?

Comment: After I posted this, I read about this, I am implementing it right now. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it if it worked.

Comment: @AeroVTP you are implementing it? Why? That function already exists in Octave.

Comment: By implementing, I meant put it in my Octave code in a way that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although imclose is a good idea, running it just one time has a much "stronger" effect on the image than just running the 'erode' and 'dilate' functions multiple times. I personally ran the erode and dilate functions 5 times, in succession, to get the best results for the earlier image. Running the Dilate and Erode commands separately give more control for good image processing.

Imclose is just a function that applies the erode and dilate functions repeatedly. In Octave, the function to dilate and erode is

```
editedImage = bwmorph(initialImage, 'dilate', 5 %number of times to apply% ); 

editedImage = bwmorph(initialImage, 'erode', 5 %number of times to apply% );
```

I also invented my own commenting structure :).

Thanks to wbest for initial imClose idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this (to an extent) with [morphological closing](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/close.htm), in Matlab it's [imclose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html). You'll need to be careful, though as noise that's too close may be included, and true blobs too far away may be excluded.